# Apache Tomcat 7 CORS Filter IE8, IE9 always return 403 response

Tags: tomcat7, cors

I was trying to implement Cross-domain requesting using AJAX CORS.
I enabled my server side by using CORS Filter of tomcat.
But for IE8,9, tomcat always returns 403.

Are there any ideas about this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should specify what request method you are using and add source code examples.

---

I can only guess, but if you are using POST method and default apache CorsFilter, the issue is in the following:
for CORS requests IE8 and IE9 use XDomainRequest object, which doesn't appear to send any Content-Type header at all and in turn, CorsFilter considers this request as INVALID (see [checkRequestType](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.42/org/apache/catalina/filters/CorsFilter.java#CorsFilter.checkRequestType%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) method).
Possible solution is to add your own CorsFilter based on apache version that handles empty Content-Type.

Answer (score 0):

Cors Filter here (http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html) is a good alternative that has no such problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```